# Insert the record in one table from another table with some criteria in oracle

Tags: oracle

I need to insert the record into one table from another table which is exact replica of other table ,condition for putting this as when a same record (for certain condition match) is coming from another table it will update the existing record and when a brand new record come it will insert the record.

I have written the query for this as below please correct me if possible.

```
INSERT INTO  TEMP1   (B,C,D,PROVIDER_ID,NATIONAL_PROVIDER_IDENTIFIER,TAXONIMY_CODE,F,G,H) 
SELECT  W.B,W.C,W.D,W.PROVIDER_ID,W.NATIONAL_PROVIDER_IDENTIFIER,W.TAXONIMY_CODE,W.F,W.G,W.H
FROM TEMP2 W LEFT JOIN  TEMP1 A ON( A.provider_id = W.provider_id
AND A.NATIONAL_PROVIDER_IDENTIFIER = W.NATIONAL_PROVIDER_IDENTIFIER
AND A.TAXONOMY_CODE = W.TAXONOMY_CODE)
WHERE  W.SOURCE_ID = 'COSMOS'
```

Comment: I am having a hard time reading that first paragraph. A punctuation problem perhaps?

Comment: with this query always the same record if matching criteria comes in temp2 it will again insert as fresh record ,it should update the already present record in temp1..please help me out to resolve this..Thanks

Comment: can you post some example input data and expected results please

Comment: if you want to "update existing record or insert an new record" please check MERGE `http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606` statement

Answer (score 0):

It's still a bit unclear to me, but it does sound like you want to be using a [MERGE statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606).

If so, your statement would look something like this (hoping I understood your data model)

```
MERGE INTO TEMP1 a
USING (
  SELECT B,C,D,PROVIDER_ID,NATIONAL_PROVIDER_IDENTIFIER,TAXONIMY_CODE,F,G,H
  FROM TEMP2
  WHERE SOURCE_ID = 'COSMOS'
) w
ON (a.provider_id = w.provider_id AND 
    a.NATIONAL_PROVIDER_IDENTIFIER = w.NATIONAL_PROVIDER_IDENTIFIER AND
    a.TAXONOMY_CODE = w.TAXONOMY_CODE
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET a.b = w.b,
             a.c = w.c,
             a.d = w.d,
             a.f = w.f,
             a.g = w.g,
             a.h = w.h
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (a.B,a.C,a.D,a.PROVIDER_ID,a.NATIONAL_PROVIDER_IDENTIFIER,a.TAXONIMY_CODE,a.F,a.G,a.H)
  VALUES (w.B,w.C,w.D,w.PROVIDER_ID,w.NATIONAL_PROVIDER_IDENTIFIER,w.TAXONIMY_CODE,w.F,w.G,w.H);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot its very much fine with me thats why i am trusting only on stack overflow..:)